# Can not install IBM-Logging plugin on Windows

Tags: ibm-cloud-plugin

I can install IBM-Logging plugin on RHEL, but can not install it on Windows. Error message is "logging-cli-win64_v1.0.2.exe: %! (MISSING)is not a valid Win32 application.". Is this installer(plugin for Windows) broken?

```
C:\bx_work>bluemix cf list-plugin-repos
'cf list-plugin-repos' を起動しています...

OK

Repo Name         URL
CF-Community      https://plugins.cloudfoundry.org
bluemix-cf-repo   https://plugins.ng.bluemix.net


C:\bx_work>bluemix cf install-plugin IBM-Logging -r bluemix-cf-repo
'cf install-plugin IBM-Logging -r bluemix-cf-repo' を起動しています...


**Attention: Plugins are binaries written by potentially untrusted authors. Install and use plugins at your own risk.**

Do you want to install the plugin IBM-Logging?> yes
Looking up 'IBM-Logging' from repository 'bluemix-cf-repo'
6094848 bytes downloaded...
Installing plugin logging-cli-win64_v1.0.2.exe...
FAILED
fork/exec C:\Users\IBM_AD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\logging-cli-win64_v1.0.2.exe: %! (MISSING)is not a valid Win32 application.

C:\bx_work>bluemix -version
bluemix version 0.5.6+5b886b4-2017-08-14T08:16:22+00:00

C:\bx_work>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can resolved this issue. Today I tried to install on my Windows again. The installation was succeeded.
This problem may be occurred on a certain version.

```
Today's environment is following. (succeed to install)

- bluemix version 0.5.6+5b886b4-2017-08-14T08:16:22+00:00

- logging-cli-win64_v1.0.13.exe

the environment on which I failed to install

- bluemix version 0.5.6+5b886b4-2017-08-14T08:16:22+00:00

- logging-cli-win64_v1.0.2.exe
```

success log is following

```
C:\work>bluemix cf list-plugin-repos
'cf list-plugin-repos' を起動しています...

OK

Repo Name         URL
CF-Community      https://plugins.cloudfoundry.org
bluemix-cf-repo   https://plugins.ng.bluemix.net


C:\work>
C:\work>bluemix cf install-plugin IBM-Logging -r bluemix-cf-repo
'cf install-plugin IBM-Logging -r bluemix-cf-repo' を起動しています...


**Attention: Plugins are binaries written by potentially untrusted authors. Install and use plugins at your own risk.**

Do you want to install the plugin IBM-Logging?> yes
Looking up 'IBM-Logging' from repository 'bluemix-cf-repo'
10556928 bytes downloaded...
Installing plugin logging-cli-win64_v1.0.13.exe...
OK
Plugin IBM-Logging v1.0.0 successfully installed.

C:\work>bluemix --version
bluemix version 0.5.6+5b886b4-2017-08-14T08:16:22+00:00

C:\work>
```